# Netbeans JLabel anchor overpowers my layout managers

Tags: netbeans, jpanel, jlabel, gridbaglayout, boxlayout

I know this has been asked alot and in various ways, and I have tried them, but with no success.  i am using netbeans and swing to create my GUI.

i have a Jlabel inside of a JPanel.  Whenver I place the label inside the panel, it automatically anchors it to the closest component which is NOT what I want.  I want to center the component, regardless of size.

However, creating custom JPanels in the "Code" section of the GUI editor to make a BoxLayout and GridBagLayout does not seem to work.  It seems no matter what, it still anchors.  You can see the attached jpg of what it is doing in my editor.[image]

Anybody have some ideas?

As mentioned, I have tried to change the "Custom Creation Code" of the JPanel to do:
new javax.swing.JPanel(new GridBagLayout());

and then removed the parent tag of my JLabel and added "Post-Creation Code" to be:
statusPanel.add(versionLabel,new GridBagConstraints());

I have also tried typing out the GridBagConstraints to say centered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get a copy of [NetBeans 7.0](http://netbeans.org/) They've just completely overhauled their [GridBagLayout Visual Designer](http://wiki.netbeans.org/NewAndNoteworthyNB70#GUI_Builder_-_New_GridBagLayout_Designer)

You should be able to achieve this quite handily with it.

Comment: Netbeans 7.0 does seem to have a pretty neat GUI editor for Layout.  i haven't figure it out yet, but I can right click the parent panel and setup the layout and popup editor window allows me to play around with it, including a "Test View" button.